# How do I seed my database with only part of my seed code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to run one or two blocks within my seeds.rb code like you can with tests and gemfiles?

For example, if I had the following code in my seeds.rb file, could I just seed the `Employee` model?

```
20.times do
  Employee.create!(name: "Bob",
                   email: Faker::Internet.email)
end

20.times do
  User.create!(name:     "Hank",
               password: "foobar") 
end
```

If this were my entire seeds.rb file, running `rake db:seed` would create 20 additional users when I only want to add more employees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an option while running `rake db:seed` like following:

```
rake db:seed users=yes
```

And, then in your code, you can access it through the following way:

```
20.times do
  Employee.create!(name: "Bob",
                   email: Faker::Internet.email)
end

if ENV["users"]
  20.times do
    User.create!(name:     "Hank",
                 password: "foobar") 
  end
end
```

Comment: So I should just put `if ENV[<variable>]` before each block I want control over?

Comment: Obviously! You need to manually put it all over, and I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, just seemed kind of inefficient at first, but really, I just need to control one or two groups.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this is the valid answer, and helped you; you can accept it.

Comment: Will do, assuming I don't see a better answer sooner. There's a 15 minute waiting period, anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following setup for a couple of years now to help my sanity.

In db/seeds I have the following files:

```
001_providers.rb
005_api_users.rb
007_mailing_lists.rb
010_countries.rb
011_us_states.rb
012_canadian_provinces.rb
013_mexican_states.rb
100_world_cities.rb
101_us_zipcodes.rb
```

My db/seeds.rb file looks like this:

```
if ENV['VERSION'].present?
  seed_files = Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'seeds', "*#{ENV['VERSION']}*.rb")]
  raise "No seed files found matching '#{ENV['VERSION']}'" if seed_files.empty?
else
  seed_files = Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'seeds', '*.rb')]
end

seed_files.sort_by{|f| File.basename(f).to_i}.each do |file|
  require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'seeds', File.basename(file, File.extname(file)))
end
```

Just a bit of ruby code to let me run one or more seed files. I can now do things like this:

```
# run them all
bin/rake db:seed

# run just 001_providers.rb
bin/rake db:seed VERSION=001

# run all seeds for the USA (probably dangerous, but if you name your seeds right, could be useful). 
bin/rake db:seed VERSION=us
```

One thing that is very important is that your seed files should be able to be run over and over and over and end up with a consistent state.  If you run your seeds over and over you'll end up with many more users than just 20.

For example, my providers one has a main loop like this:

```
# providers is a hash of attributes...
providers.each_with_index do |(code, attrs), i|
  p = Provider.find_by(code: code) || Provider.new(code: code)       p.update!(attrs)
end
```

This way regardless of when I run it, I always get back exactly the providers I defined in my hash.

Comment: This is very neat, I like it. I think I may go with Arslan's answer, but if this application gets any bigger and more complex, I'll definitely look more into implementing this.