# Is there a way to db:seed only one table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a lot of data in my seeds, and have them separated into multiple files. I'm wondering if there is a way I can seed only one of these tables? In Laravel, I know it's possible to separate seeders into classes and then call:

```
php artisan db:seed --class CertainTableSeeder.
```

Is there a way to do this in Rails?

I have two files with a lot of seed data, joined through this function in seeds.rb

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].sort.each do |seed|
    load seed
  end
```

I've tried running commands like

```
rake db:seed SEED="CountriesTableSeeder.rb"
```

Only to find that this still reverts to running a normal db:seed, and my seeders are set up to destroy the table before each seed, but I'd rather not destroy the information from all tables each time I seed.

Comment: this answer probably can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41936080/938947

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I seed my database with only part of my seed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056942/how-do-i-seed-my-database-with-only-part-of-my-seed-code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With below custom rake file, you can have multiple seed files in `db/seeds/` folder.

```
# lib/tasks/custom_seed.rake
# lib/tasks/custom_seed.rake
namespace :db do
  namespace :seed do

    Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].each do |filename|
      task_name = File.basename(filename, '.rb').intern

      task task_name => :environment do
        load(filename)
      end
    end

    task :all => :environment do
      Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].sort.each do |filename|
        load(filename)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Then, in order to run specific seed file, you can just run

```
rake db:seed:seed_file_name
```

To run all the seeds file with order in that `db/seeds` folder, run below command

```
rake db:seed:all
```

Comment: Dude, this solved my problem perfectly! Thank you !

Comment: Is there any way to keep the default db:seed behaviour as well? (no need to specify :all?)

Comment: @Jonathan, You could just copy and paste the contents of the `all` task into your `db/seeds.rb` file (which is what `rails db:seed` runs)...

Answer (score 0):

To run only one seed file, perhaps in a folder, the following will do

```
bundle exec rails db:seed:folder_if_any:file_with_seed
```

So for your case, this would do

```
bundle exec rails db:seed:countries_table_seeder
```

PS: If you find that the command `bundle exec rails` doesn't work, use `bundle exec rake` instead